# Spark - Joining 2 paired rdds

Tags: apache-spark

I have 2 paired RDDs:
Paired RDD1:
[K1, V1], [K2, V2], [K3, V3], [K7, V7], [K8, V8]

Paired RDD2:
[K1, V12], [K2, V22], [K3, V32], [K4, V4], [K5, V5], [K6, V6]

I want join these 2 RDDs such that my output should look like this

Paired RDD3:
[K1, V1], [K2, V2], [K3, V3], [K4, V4], [K5, V5], [K6, V6], [K7, V7], [K8, V8]

Please provide your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val rdd3 = rdd2.union(rdd1)
returned the required output.

Thanks.

Comment: you should accept your own answer, or delete the question.